# form clean method vs model clean method vs model field validator

Tags: python, django

I have a model with the field **facebook_link**.

With the help of a regular expression I want to validate if this link is really a facebook link.

The user can enter the facebook link in a form.

Should I place my validation in the clean method of the [form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation) field,

in the clean method of the [model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) field

or should I use a a custom [validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/validators/#module-django.core.validators)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read the documentation correctly, I think the answer to your question is **none of the above**. According to the [validators documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/validators/), a built-in [RegexValidator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/validators/#regexvalidator) is available for you to validate data using regular expressions. This is likely what you should use (don't reinvent the wheel).

Technically speaking, however, I think validators are the right place to put this kind of logic, precisely because they can be used either on forms or models. That re-usability alone makes them worthwhile.

Comment: That's the perfect solution, I didn't know this validator. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a **RegexValidator**, place it in your **model field** definition, and use a **ModelForm** so that it will call the clean method on your model field.